# Unable to save all users into SharePoint list

Tags: sharepoint-2013

I am creating a list item using the code below:

```
    var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current(); 
    var dfd = $.Deferred(); 
    var targetList = context.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(listName);
    context.load(targetList); 
    var itemCreateInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation(); 
    var listItem = targetList.addItem(itemCreateInfo);

    listItem.set_item("Title", listValues[0].Title); 
    listItem.set_item("Department", listValues[0].Department);  
    listItem.set_item("TeamMembers", listValues[0].TeamMembers);
    listItem.set_item("Notes", listValues[0].Notes);  
    listItem.update();
    context.executeQueryAsync( 
        function () { 
            var id = listItem.get_id();
            if (listValues[0].Files.length > 0) {   
                 if (fileCountCheck <= listValues[0].Files.length - 1) {                 
                     loopFileUpload(listName, id, listValues, fileCountCheck).then( 
                     function () { }, 
                     function (sender, args) { 
                         dfd.reject(sender, args); 
                     } ); 
                } 
            } 
            else { dfd.resolve(fileCountCheck);             } 
        }, 
        function (sender, args) {       }   );
```

TeamMembers is a string containing the UserIds of all the users selected in a people picker, in the format `;#564;#5454;#56;#865;#`

It is working if only one person is selected.
I noticed that when there are multiple users selected, many of them are not getting saved into the list.

What could be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I changed the data passed into the user field as below:

`TeamMembers` now has a value in the format `";#" + this.user1.get_id() + ";#" + this.user1.get_loginName() + ";" + this.user2.get_id() + ";#" + this.user2.get_loginName()`.

With the latest format, I am able to successfully save all the usernames into the list.